# Am I slowing down my Raspberry Pi Zero W by setting cpu_freq=250?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspberry-pi-zero

I use this [library](https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x) over SPI to control some RGB Leds.

When using the Raspberry Pi 3, I have to set `cpu_freq=250` on `/boot/config`, as far as I've understood, it has something to do with the bluetooth device running on the default serial port.

Now, using the Raspberry Pi Zero W I'm algo having to set that flag.

My questions is, what is the correct cpu clock for both Pi 3 and Zero W, and am I slowing my Pi performance by setting this flag?